# Latin squares using fixed word lists

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

Consider the problem of constructing a latin square of order $N$, using only row and column values from a given ***word list*** ($W$) containing some subset of the $N!$ possible word values.

For example, for $N = 4$, given word list {1234, 2341, 3412, 4123}, we can obtain 4 latin squares:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 1 & 2 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}$$

The question naturally arises - for given $N$, how large must $|W|$ be in order to ***guarantee*** that at least one latin square is obtainable?

I'll call this minimum word list size $M_N$.

So, for given $N$, $M_N$ is the least integer such that a Latin square is obtainable from all $W$ with $|W|=M_N$.

We have $M_2 = 2, M_3 = 5$, and $M_4 = 18$, these are easily established. As a proportion of the $N!$ words applicable, these are 1, 5/6 and 3/4 respectively.

For $N=5$, I have found a set of 96 words which doesn't yield a latin square, so $M_5 > 96$.

Note that $18 = 4! - 3!$, $96 = 5! - 4!,$ and that we can always construct a set $W_N$ that contains all $N!$ words *except* those beginning with $1$ (or any other value) from which no Latin squares can be obtained.

So $M_N = N! - (N-1)! + k_N$, with $k_N > 0$, and we suspect, but have yet to prove, that $k_N = 1$ for all $N$.

Comment: $M_5 > 66$. Finding a 66-word $W$ that can't produce a Latin Square took 2 million set generations.

Comment: The question doesn't say what you apparently want it to say. You seem to mean: For given $N$, $M_N$ is the least integer such that a Latin square is obtainable from all $W$ with $|W|=M_N$.

Comment: That definition is correct, although I really thought that this was clear from what I said. Nevertheless I have included it above.

Comment: What's $M_3$? What's $M_2$?

Comment: @JimWhite: No, it wasn't clear. You talk about a given word list $W$ and then ask how large $|W|$ must be in order to guarantee that at least one Latin square is attainable. It's not clear that "guarantee" implies universal quantification over all possible word lists; I had to think about it for a while before understanding that you meant to imply this.

Comment: Gerry, I've included those results above. Joriki, my apologies, point taken!

Comment: You might want to consider the reduced problem, with the first line always being the identical permutation and all the other words being derangements.

Comment: That's a good idea!  Another is to use known word-lists of size $K$ with no solutions (no LS's can be formed), then test these lists with additional members. This can quickly identify new lower-bounds for $M_N$. I've already revised the $M_5$ result quite significantly.

Comment: Updated $M_6$ using list-expansion method. $M_6 > 259$

Comment: Aagghh! The penny has finally dropped - clearly $M_N = N! - (N-1)! + 1$. We set $W$  as all $N!$ words except those $(N-1)!$ words beginning with $1$, and no Latin square is obtainable without adding one entry.  I was so immersed in the trees I lost sight of the forest! 

So $M_5 = 97$, $M_6 = 601$, etc ...

Comment: The only question remaining is whether we should remove this question!

Comment: No -- if you can prove that answer, it would be best to write it up as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Ok. I need to prove no set $W_N$ with $|W_N| > N! - (N-1)!$ can fail to yield a Latin square ...